# Воспроизведение музыки в JAR

Tags: java, jar

Есть jar, который генерит IDEA. В нем прописан путь к файлу с музыкой 
`.//src//super-mario.mp3`
При запуске через идею работает, через jar -- нет. Куда положить файл с музыкой, чтобы он подтягивался из самого jar? т.е. чтобы не нужно было дополнительно кидать на ПК файл с музыкой. С картинками все ок, а музыка не работает

Comment: В resources положить.

Answer (score 1):

В корневой папке проекта нужно создать папку, куда будут добавляться все ресурсы, а также обязательно отметить ее как ресурсную(ПКМ на папке->Mark Directory As-> Resources Root). А дальше подгружать с помощью `ClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResources("super-mario.mp3");`

Comment: а как потом скастовать из этого File? Мне нужен объект именно File

Comment: @Ксения    try {
                File file=new File(ClassName.class.getResource("super-mario.mp3").toURI());
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

Comment: Надеюсь, что понятно)

Comment: папка res почему-то не попадает в jar. в идее все работает

Comment: Когда собираешь jar, нужно вручную эту папку добавить, так как по умолчанию добавляется только src

Comment: в джар файл добавляется. .jar -> resources -> .mp3 . но звука все равно нет "File mario = new File(Player.class.getClassLoader().getResource("resources/super-mario.mp3").toURI());
            AP = javazoom.jl.player.advanced.jlap.playMp3(mario,pl);"

Comment: Нужно не resources/super-mario.mp3, a просто super-mario.mp3 подгружать

Comment: тоже самое. при запуске через консоль ошибка при запуске из консоли ошибка "http://java.lang.illegalargumentexception: URI is not hierarchical"

Comment: почему то не прописан Class Path, так и должно быть или его руками нужно добавлять?

Comment: решилось изменением атрибутов, чтобы AP = javazoom.jl.player.advanced.jlap.playMp3(url, 0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, pl);.  принимал InputStream